# Mocking local api in cucumber tests

Tags: ajax, api, tdd, mocking, cucumber

I am writing an app that access a local that lives on a separate path on my own server via ajax requests. However, I want to test the app with cucumber and mock out the backend. Is there something like artiface or sham_rack that would let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MockJson to simulate the response:
[MockJson website](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using VCR:

http://relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr

It allows you to record the requests to the external service once, and then play back the recorded responses when running your tests.

Comment: Does vcr support non net:HTTP requests?

Comment: It supports a pretty good range of ruby HTTP libraries, although I don't think it will be much use if you are just making an ajax request directly to an external site through javascript.

Comment: VCR supports Net::HTTP, Typhoeus, Excon, HTTPClient, Patron, EM HTTP Request and Curb.  Also, I've used it for ajax requests before, by setting up a simple rack proxy app, using VCR's rack middleware with that, and having my ajax requests submit to my local rack app in test mode.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/?